# oracle apex 5.0 classic report headings disappear on sort

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I'm using a classic report to display my data.  The headings are based on a hidden variable value (&M0. is the first heading) and I have the sortable option set to ON.  I'm also using the IRR Region Template.  When I click on a header and sort on it, the headings disappear and all of my nice jQuery code does not take effect (I have jQuery code that does gridlines).  Has anyone experienced this before?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at session state what is the value of MO? Probably when you sort region you make partial refresh and not submit M0. You can use **Page items to submit** section to send MO to the server. Below is Help of **Page Items To Submit**:
*Enter page or application items to be set into session state when the region is refreshed by a partial page refresh. For multiple items, separate each item name with a comma. You can type in the name or pick from the list of available items. If you pick from the list and there is already text entered, then a comma is placed at the end of the existing text, followed by the item name returned from the list.
The region can be refreshed with partial page refresh either during pagination, if Enable Partial Page Refresh is set to Yes), or with the Refresh action within a Dynamic Action.
These page items can then be used in the where condition of the Region Source SQL Query to restrict the query result.*